# usernameExsist function c++ Object-orienten progrmming

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class:

```
class Account {
private:
    string name;
    unsigned int age;
    string username;
    string password;
};
```

In my main program I need to make a `bool usernameExsist(Account* userAccount, Account* acountList[], int numberOfElements)` function that returns true if the name is found. But I have problems with the arrays and the implementation.I entered some information in the class: `Account first=Account("Max", 18,"maxx34","12345adc");`Can someone help me with the implementation?! Thanks.

Comment: Add your try and you'll get help.

Comment: Since you have problems with arrays, use `std::vector`. :-)

Comment: If you haven't already, look towards [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: Implement a method that compares another `Account` by name.  You could also overload `operator<` to compare to another account by name.

Comment: `  bool usernameExists(Account* userAccount, Account* accountList[],
  int numberOfElements) {
 bool jap = true;
 while (jap) {
  cout << "Enter username: ";
  string name;
  cin >> name;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if (name == accountList[i]) {
    return true;
   } else
    return false;
  }
 }

}  ` Thanks my try. I tryed lost of thing, but nothing works.

Comment: Post this as an edit, please. Also, why are you passing pointers to functions? Did you not learn about references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class `vector` which relieve you from the burden of arrays and size...

Here is an example that you could modify to meet your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Account {
    public:
        Account(string, unsigned int, string, string);
    //private: // in your example un-comment private and provide public getters instead.
        string name;
        unsigned int age;
        string username;
        string password;
};

Account::Account(string Name, unsigned int Age, string UserName, string Password) : 
    name(Name), age(Age), username(UserName), password(Password){

}


bool usernameExsist(string, vector<Account>);


int main(){

    std::vector< Account > vec;
    string name;
    unsigned int age;
    string username;
    string password;

    while(1){
        cout << "name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Age: ";
        cin >> age;
        if(!age || age < 0)
            break;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "username: ";
        getline(cin, username);
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "password: ";
        getline(cin, password);
        cout << endl;
        cin.ignore();

        Account a(name, age, username, password);
        vec.push_back(a);
    }

    cout << usernameExsist("Max", vec) << endl;


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool usernameExsist(string name, vector<Account> vec){
    const int size = vec.size();
    for(int i(0); i != size; ++i)
        if(name == vec[i].name){
            cout << "Found at: " << i << endl;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have a ton of feedback, up to you whether you wanna implement any of it: your `usernameExsist` function compares the name, not the `username`. Despite OP's spelling, you should consider spelling the function correctly. Both parameters should be `const&`. The only way to break your `while` loop is by not inputting an age. You can omit the local variables altogether and just store the data straight into `Account`. For demonstration purposes, I'd have omitted all the unnecessary stuff from `Account` (including the constructor), which would make your code shorter and clearer,. Use ranged `for`

Comment: I'd have probably not worried about demonstrating the io aspects of reading into `Account`, I'd have just replaced it entirely by adding two `Account` and finding one. Again, it just makes the code in the answer shorter which in turn makes it clearer the important aspect (the function to check if the username _exsists_)

Comment: @Tas I focused only on the class vector but not about the remaining stuff. Anyway thanks and i will edit it later on.